# How to handle variable number of arguments

Tags: lua

I've understood that `arg` is deprecated and is no longer supported in later versions of Lua. I have a lot of functions written in Lua 5.1 that have variable number of arguments and I am moving to Lua 5.4 but I have no idea how to handle them without `arg`.

```lua
-- Without arg, nil entries are ignored.
local function printMyArgumentsA( ... )
    local t = {...}
    for i, v in pairs( t ) do
        print( i, v )
    end
    print("")
end
printMyArgumentsA( 1, nil, 3, nil )


-- With arg, I know how many entries there were, so I know which are nil.
local function printMyArgumentsB( ... )
    for i = 1, arg.n do
        print( i, arg[i] )
    end
    print("")
end
printMyArgumentsB( 1, nil, 3, nil )
```

How would I get the number of arguments sent to a function without the use of `arg` in later versions of Lua?

Comment: I saw that someone suggested using `#t` in a now deleted reply. This wouldnt work since it would "fail" at the first nil value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [table.pack](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.pack). It stores an `n` field, just like in the old code.

```
local function printMyArgumentsB( ... )
    local arg <const> = table.pack(...)
    for i = 1, arg.n do
        print( i, arg[i] )
    end
    print()
end
printMyArgumentsB( 1, nil, 3, nil )
```

If you don't want to make a table, you could use `select('#', ...)` to get the number of values in `...`. See [select](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-select) here.